# zoomable chart | Scope problem when zooming

Tags: d3.js

I want to adapt the zoomable chart visualizations found [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-area-chart) or [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html).

However, on those examples, things like axes and scales are in global scope and can be called from anywhere.

I want to have a `Timeline` class that encapsulates the visualisation and thus there are no variables in global scope.

The issue is here

```
this.canvas_.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([.1, 20000])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('zoom', this.zoomed_));
```

I have defined the `zoomed_` method:

```
zoomed_() {
    let newXScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(this.scaleX_);
    let newYScale = this.scaleY_;

    // update axes
    this.gX_.call(this.AxisX_.scale(newXScale));
    this.gX_.call(this.AxisY_.scale(newYScale));
  }
```

However, the issue is that when `this.zoomed_` is called, the scope is no longer the same and `this` points to the object `this.canvas_` points to, which is an `svg` element. Therefore, no such thing as `this.scaleX_` is ever found.

What is the best way to deal with this? I can imagine there are imaginative ways of accessing the parent methods from a child component but probably not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with

```
this.canvas_.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([.1, 20000])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('zoom', this.zoomed_.bind(this)));
```

Binding with `bind(this)` allows to access the parent elements.

Comment: not accepting in case where is a better answer.